# Creating an email account programmatically

Tags: java, android, smtp, gmail, spam

I have a project which requires sending silent emails. The problem is that I do not want to prompt the user to enter his username and password as I know most of them won't (and they should't :)
My main problem is to find a way to have a valid sender. So I thought of several approaches:

1. Prompting user to enter his username and password, and encrypt those credentials when storing them on the client side.
2. Send the email through a fake account (Don't know of any SMTP server that allows that with no authentication)
3. Prompt user to create an account, and somehow grab the user name and password (Don't know of any API which allows that, as it is provider specific... perhaps use a web view?)

I do not have any intentions such as spamming a user. He will be in full control of what needs to be sent. What would be the best way to have a valid sender in order to send emails silently? I've looked into ACTION.SEND_TO, however, that one won't work since it would require direct user interaction.

Any ideas? Or any other ways in which I can have a valid sender?

Comment: -1 Sending emails with no valid reply address is awfully common these days, but that still doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could use google appspot and then get the auth using android, and then post it programmatically by the Google account. Have never used but should be possible. Check this [How can my appengine app send mail using the senderid of domain that installed the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066542/how-can-my-appengine-app-send-mail-using-the-senderid-of-domain-that-installed-t)

Edit: 
Check this link. 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail

You will have to use this to send email on server side and from device you could just pass a command what to send

Answer (score 0):

You could try to send a SMTP request to an anonymous SMTP server (aka [Open mail relay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mail_relay)) the problem is finding one, they do still exist.

Can't give you a list but here is an online tool to test if a SMTP server is open relay. Happy hunting

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be, create a gmail account and use it as from account in your smtp client code. In that case, if you need the user's identity, you can fetch the user's primary gmail account through android api and attach it in your email's subject line.